# Replacement for NOAA Seamless Raster Navigational Chart Services?

Tags: leaflet, maps, noaa

NOAA [stopped their Seamless Raster Navigational Chart Services](https://nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/updates/coast-survey-to-shut-down-the-raster-navigational-chart-tile-service-and-other-related-services/) URL this year.  I was using it in a simple leaflet.js project, and need a replacement or update.

Going through the various documents on using their new vector data gets me lost *very quickly*.  Is there a "simple" workaround?  Or a suggestion or pointer to simpler documentation that doesn't require significant GIS knowledge?  Or an alternative service, similar to Open Street Maps but more nautically focused?

Thanks.